# Call to Serilog log writer never returns

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, serilog

I'm trying to add Serilog logging to my project (ASP .NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.6.1)) and I can't get it past the actual logging of the statement.

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage( "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=zzzzzzzz;AccountKey=xxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug, "dev-logs", "{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/log.txt" )
    .CreateLogger();
_logger.Information( "testing" );
```

If I put a breakpoint in place, I can step over the `.CreateLogger()` statement, but if I try to step past the `.Information()` call, it never makes it to the next statement. No exceptions are thrown, and the entry never makes it to the log file. The file is created, but remains empty. What am I missing? I've tried this with version 1.2.3 and 1.1.1. I've also tried both 2.7.1 and 2.8.0 of Serilog itself. Is there something wrong with my connection string (in which case, how is the file created empty)? What other settings or changes do I need to make in order to get this running properly?

Other packages that got added to my project:
..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.1.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll
..\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.3.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
..\packages\Serilog.2.8.0\lib\net46\Serilog.dll
..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage.1.2.3\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage.dll
..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.File.4.0.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.File.dll
..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.2.1.1\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.dll

Comment: Is it possible to break the debugger and capture a stack trace from the "hung" state?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't a perfect solution but I try the version 1.0.1 and it's working.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage/1.0.1